# Creating a reduce method that can handle any number of objects with unique Ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, reduce

I am trying to use the reduce method to sort through an array of objects. My goal is to create a reduce method that can handle any number of objects (with unique eventIds). The desired output would be formatted like this but with the capability to handle more than just five unique eventIds

[Desired Output]

```
     (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
       0:
          eventId: "12345"
          total: Array(3)
            0: {total: 123}
            1: {total: 45}
            2: {total: 123}
            length: 3

       1: {total: Array(3), eventId: '12347'}
       2: {total: Array(3), eventId: '12349'}
       3: {total: Array(3), eventId: '12348'}
       4: {total: Array(3), eventId: '12346'}
```

To get the output above I used this reduce method.

[Reduce Method]

```
      const sortedSalesData = salesData.reduce((acc, obj) => {

      for ( let i = 0; i<salesData.length; i++) {

        if (obj.eventId === salesData[i].eventId ) {

          acc[i].eventId = salesData[i].eventId;
          acc[i].total = [...acc[i].total, {total: obj.total}];

          return acc;
        }
      };
      
  },[{total:[]},{total:[]},{total:[]},{total:[]},{total:[]}]);
```

But I'm not sure how to set it up to handle more than those five unique eventIds. Below is the original array for reference.

[Original Array]

```
    const salesData = 
    [
      { eventId: '12345', total: 123 },
      { eventId: '12347', total: 45 },
      { eventId: '12349', total: 78 },
      { eventId: '12348', total: 123 },
      { eventId: '12346', total: 45 },
      { eventId: '12349', total: 78 },
      { eventId: '12347', total: 123 },
      { eventId: '12345', total: 45 },
      { eventId: '12348', total: 78 },
      { eventId: '12345', total: 123 },
      { eventId: '12347', total: 45 },
      { eventId: '12346', total: 78 },
      { eventId: '12349', total: 123 },
      { eventId: '12348', total: 45 },
      { eventId: '12346', total: 78 },
     ];
```

The hangup is getting it to a place where it can handle any number of unique events without having to add an additional {total:[]} at the end of the method.

Comment: "an array that contains as many objects as is needed to house all the unique eventIds all the totals associated with that eventID from the initial array" -- this is hard to understand. Can you show what this looks like for your input array here? I also don't understand the meaning of the last data structure you show. Thanks.

Comment: Went back and made some edits, sorry that was confusing!

Comment: Looks better, although I usually recommend showing the code output (JSON-like) rather than the weird console format that Chrome offers with the collapsed menus and extra info, but it seems clear enough. This is a sort of odd output structure--usually, when you're grouping on a key like `eventId`, you probably want a map of the keys pointing to an array of the values. The inner `total` key as the only key per object also seems like extra info that makes it harder to actually use the data structure. How large is the dataset (how efficient does it need to be)?

Comment: I agree, the chrome format is clunky. The goal is to build something that could theoretically handle thousands of unique events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wan t to iterate over the initial array (obj), insert the iterated element on a new array (acc) if eventId doesn't exist yet on said array, when it does exist (accObj), you want to push the total object of the current element (obj) onto the total array of the new element (accObj)?

I think this does what you need:

```js
let array = [
  { eventId: '12345', total: 123 },
  { eventId: '12347', total: 45 },
  { eventId: '12349', total: 78 },
  { eventId: '12348', total: 123 },
  { eventId: '12346', total: 45 },
  { eventId: '12349', total: 78 },
  { eventId: '12347', total: 123 },
  { eventId: '12345', total: 45 },
  { eventId: '12348', total: 78 },
  { eventId: '12345', total: 123 },
  { eventId: '12347', total: 45 },
  { eventId: '12346', total: 78 },
  { eventId: '12349', total: 123 },
  { eventId: '12348', total: 45 },
  { eventId: '12346', total: 78 },
]

let reducedArray = array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  console.log("Element " + JSON.stringify(obj));
  let accObj = acc.find(accObj => accObj.eventId === obj.eventId);
  if(accObj != undefined) {
    console.log("Found element: " + JSON.stringify(accObj) + ".")
    console.log("Pushing "+ obj.total +" to total.")
    accObj.total.push(obj.total);
  } else {
    accObj = { eventId: obj.eventId, total: [obj.total] };
    console.log("Pushing new element to list: " + JSON.stringify(accObj));
    acc.push(accObj);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(reducedArray));
```

The trick is on the `find` method, I'm searching my own reducing list to see if it already has an element that shares eventId with the old array.

Comment: You read my mind! Thank you for the added logs, It made it a lot easier for me to follow and visualize what is happening behind the scenes!

Comment: No problem, in the beginning it's really is troublesome to know what `reduce` is doing. When we understand that what it does is simply perpetuate one single object through all the elements inside an array, it gets easier to use and explore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no fan of .reduce so here is an easy solution without it

```js
    const salesData = 
    [
      { eventId: '12345', total: 123 },
      { eventId: '12347', total: 45 },
      { eventId: '12349', total: 78 },
      { eventId: '12348', total: 123 },
      { eventId: '12346', total: 45 },
      { eventId: '12349', total: 78 },
      { eventId: '12347', total: 123 },
      { eventId: '12345', total: 45 },
      { eventId: '12348', total: 78 },
      { eventId: '12345', total: 123 },
      { eventId: '12347', total: 45 },
      { eventId: '12346', total: 78 },
      { eventId: '12349', total: 123 },
      { eventId: '12348', total: 45 },
      { eventId: '12346', total: 78 },
     ]
     
     let reduced = {}
     salesData.forEach(elem=> {
       if(reduced[elem.eventId] !== undefined){
         reduced[elem.eventId].push(elem.total)
       } else {
         reduced[elem.eventId] = [elem.total]
       }
     })
     reduced = Object.keys(reduced).map(elem => {
       return({eventId: elem, total:reduced[elem]})
     })
     console.log(reduced)
```

Comment: After raking myself over the coals trying to figure this out before coming here with the problem I am not a fan of .reduce either! Thank you for taking the time to provide your input on the problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Building up on the [answer of JeanJacquesGourdin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72997464/3653975) I'd like to add a solution with reduce that should be a little more performant then both answers (at the time of writing).

I can only encourage to get into the mindset of reduce. Once understood, it is fairly easy to use.

```js
const array = [
  {eventId: '12345', total: 123},
  {eventId: '12347', total: 45},
  {eventId: '12345', total: 45},
]

const output = Object.entries(array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (!acc[obj.eventId]) {
    acc[obj.eventId] = []
  }
  acc[obj.eventId].push(obj.total)
  return acc;
}, {})).map(([eventId, total]) => ({
  eventId,
  total
}));

console.log(output);
```

The only thing I dislike about this approach is the `Object.entries` which seems so out of place and breaks the piping flow. However, it is more performant and, in my opinion, also easier to read.